# Protractor angular js

Tags: angularjs, protractor

How can i access this class

[As the  + icon showing this class name   I want to click on that + icon to add a new DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jhgC.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
let addButton = element(by.css('.fa.kd-add'));
addButton.click();
```

[Documentation](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.css) here.

Comment: If it's just to click I'd not create a variable for it simple `$('.fa.kd-add').click()` would be sufficient - `$` is a shorthand for element by css

Comment: You're right. The reason I used a variable was in case it needs to be used for other things, e.g. checking it's present or visible. I always use the $ but thought the longer `element(by(css` would be more understandable if they're just starting out with Protractor.